# Should member variables be initialized inline or in the constructor?

Tags: apex, bestpractice

Is there or should there be a hard and fast rule for whether to initialize a class's member variables inline vs. inside a constructor? Consider the following two approaches that I *think* are functionally equivalent.

### Init inline

```
public class Foo {
    private Integer counter = 0;

    public Foo() {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

Semantically this approach seems cleaner, as it tells the reader that this member variable exists and immediately shows its default value.

### Init in constructor

```
public class Foo {
    private Integer counter;

    public Foo() {
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

I believe this is how I was taught, but I can't really explain why this would be better than doing the inline init.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a constructor, don't use inline initialization. This leads to scattered initialization; you now have to check more than one place to figure out where something got its value from.

If you don't use a constructor, then inline initialization is okay, and probably preferred. Also, it is usually easier to inline static variable initialization than making a static block.

All that said, avoid mixing and matching. Use one method consistently. This makes for maintainable code.

Answer (score 2):

If you actually know the variable value beforehand then i'd suggest doing initialisation at the place of variable definition. 
Constructor initialisation is for cases where you want to pass a value from the code creating an instance of your class.

consider following code (this is a silly and not practical example but demonstrates my point)

```
public class Foo {
    private Integer counter;
    //...
    //...some other code here
    //...

    private Integer counterAndSome = counter + 1; //what do you think will happen here? Answer = NPE

    public Foo() {
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a technical answer to this but have a logical one.

I always prefer initializing in constructor as it gives me the option to dynamically assigning the value depending upon the object I am creating.

On the other hand, if you don't have a constructor defined(i.e using default constructor), you can assign the required values and default values inline. It comes handy as you don't have to write a zero-parameter constructor just to assign default values.